# using readFile() and writeFile() functions from exceljs in cypress

Tags: cypress

I need to update an excel sheet after running some lines of code in cypress; *Exceljs* allows us to do so using the readFile() function, then updating the value in a particular cell and finally, saving the file using writeFile() function as shown below
[image]

***The shown code works perfectly***, but I need to add this to my cypress project. When I do this cypress ignores this piece of code. I am calling the following two functions to verify the output:

```
  cy.updateMySheet('qaautomation.xlsx')  
  cy.myFunction('my sample text!')
```

Both of these functions are custom commands as cypress allows us to do so using the command.js file present in the cypress/support/ folder.

- The first function, updateMySheet(), is the one that has the issue
- The second function is just written to show that there is no error in using custom commands

I have added some cy.log('here') commands at multiple places to see where the issue is and as seen in the output, the control never enters the scope of the readFile() function[image]

### Output

[image]

How can I integrate the shown piece of code with cypress?

Comment: Hi Sarmad. Looks like your command is missing a `return` statement above `workbook.xlsx.readFile ...`?

Comment: Hey @AlexIzbas , I added return to the said location but it throws this error now "Can't read property 'F_OK' of undefined" and specifies this path 'node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js:3:1' for the error

Comment: Are you using it in a NodeJs or browser environment?

this issue is caused usually because `exceljs` uses different modules in the browser and node environment. The first in mind is to update your node version and run again, or try explicitly import the workbook: `import { Workbook } from 'exceljs/excel'`

Comment: I think cypress uses browser environment and this might be the cause of the error. The first screenshot that I have added in my question is my "writeData.js" file, and by running this command `node .\cypress\functions\writeData.js` I can update my excel sheet.